# Read_commited_snapshot still have read locks

Tags: sql-server-2008, locking

We are running a database system with MS SQL 2008 R2, and the client software access this using Entity Framework 4. We also have a merge replication and the servers are running on a virtual environment.

We are experiencing performance issues on one of our servers. When we investigate we see that we have a lot of shared read locks that blocks updates, and this appears to be the source of our problems. To fix this temporarily we tried to implement `Read_Commited_snapshot` :

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;

ALTER DATABASE MyDB
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

And verfied this with 
`select is_read_committed_snapshot_on,snapshot_isolation_state_desc,* from sys.databases where name = 'MyDB'`. After this the cpu load on all cores whent to 100% for about 1 hour and then started idling around 20-40%. But we still have performance issues. When I investingate the performance montior, I can still se that some of the large entity framework queries first creates a few object locks, and then start to create page locks (shared). How can this be, what am I missing here?

Oh.. by the way, I have tried to restart the server, and the virutal hosting environment looks good according to the hosting company.

Comment: Both NOLOCK and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT help to *reduce* locks, but they don't necessarily make them zero. Where did you get the idea that you would never have read locks? Is there some over-promising Microsoft documentation that needs to be corrected, or some blog content that needs some pitchforks?

Comment: Restarting the SQL Server instance will do nothing but unload pages from memory, which will require disk reads to get the data back into memory and probably only serves to exacerbate performance problems

Comment: When transactions running under row versioning-based isolation read data, the read operations do not acquire shared (S) locks on the data being read, and therefore do not block transactions that are modifying data [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050(v=sql.105).aspx]

Comment: You need to read the next sentence, too, and remember that "no blocking" does not mean "no locking". Emphasis mine: *...the overhead of locking resources is **minimized** as the number of locks acquired is **reduced**.* Note that locking isn't **eliminated**!

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to prove that *locking* is not eliminated by `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` (or even `NOLOCK)`; only *blocking* can be eliminated (and not necessarily in all cases, for example altering the table can obviously cause blocking, and hints like `TABLOCKX` can block certain types of other operations).

Do this in one window:

```
CREATE DATABASE floob;
GO

ALTER DATABASE floob SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
GO

ALTER DATABASE floob SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
GO

USE floob;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.splunge([object_id] INT, x CHAR(4000));

INSERT dbo.splunge([object_id], x) 
  SELECT [object_id], name 
  FROM sys.all_columns;
```

Now in a bunch of other windows, do this (and feel free to sprinkle a few with `NOLOCK` hints, too):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM dbo.splunge;
```

Note that none of them will block any others (even if some perform updates or even table modifications, as long as those are committed). But after you have started several of these, you can in another window check `sys.dm_tran_locks` and validate that, indeed, shared locks are taken at the database level, and that you shouldn't confuse locking and blocking:

```
SELECT resource_type, request_mode, request_type, request_owner_type
  FROM sys.dm_tran_locks 
  WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID(N'floob')
    AND request_session_id <> @@SPID;
```

Results should be a bunch of these, one for each query window:

```
resource_type  request_mode  request_type  request_owner_type
-------------  ------------  ------------  ----------------------------
DATABASE       S             LOCK          SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE
```

Snapshot isolation can resolve some of your performance issues, but not all of them. Perhaps you should take a look at the queries EF is generating and try to tweak those instead of trying to improve performance by somehow convincing SQL Server that it never has to lock anything...

Comment: I know that locking is not eliminated. The queries will e.g. have shcema locks. But blocking shared locks on pages and tables should be eliminated, but I still have them

Comment: @Furnes can you please show evidence of ***blocking***? All you've said is that you see ***locking*** in performance monitor, and haven't even indicated how you are so sure that the locking you see has anything to do with your performance issue(s).